# Why SQL returns an Array instead of an Object?

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server-2016

I'm using SQL SERVER 2016 JSON result, but I don't know why it converts everything to array, e.g. if I execute the following query it returns an array instead of an object:

```
SELECT 1 AS One,2 AS Two,3 AS Three
FOR JSON PATH
```

The result is:

```
[{"One":1,"Two":2,"Three":3}]
```

But I would like it to return:

```
{"One":1,"Two":2,"Three":3}
```

Also I tested this query, but the result was the same, again an array:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 AS One,2 AS Two,3 AS Three
FOR JSON PATH
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just need the `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` option:

```
SELECT 1 AS One,2 AS Two,3 AS Three
FOR JSON PATH ,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```